# How can I get an expression to return a floating-point number?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

Here is the data I am working with. It was imported from Excel and `Double` was the data-type as shown below:

```
|Store| Multi      | Total       |
+-----+------------+-------------+
|5971 |1643.5765892|2168.17562315|
|5977 |821.7882946 |1151.7620749 |
|5975 |1307.5744786|1787.7159673 |
```

I put this table in an expression and divided Multi into Total but the query when run does not show the floating-point number (percentage). I have tried putting conversion functions around the parts of the expression and running it but it just won't return a floating-point number. Is there anything that I can do?

Here is the expression:

```
Expr1: [Multi]/[Total]
```

Microsoft Access 2013 currently returns zeroes.

Comment: what do you mean by "divided multi into total"? Which one was divided by the other one??

Comment: do upload the expression that you have created because without it, the question is difficult to understand

Comment: Incredibly hard to understand.

Comment: ok I added the expression. It's just dividing one column into the other.

Answer (score 0):

When I copy and paste the data into excel and re-import the data into Microsoft Access 2013 the problem is solved. So instead of a MS Access problem I think I am dealing with a data import issue.